# webpack 5 does not accept any setting for devtool

Tags: javascript, webpack

When building with webpack 5, I get the error:

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$".
   BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict.
   Please strictly follow the order of the keywords in the pattern.
```

In my webpack.config.js however, I have the setting:

```
    devtool: 'eval-cheap-source-map',
```

Ive also tried `eval` as value which also does not work, although this website (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) seems to indicate that it should.
I do not understand, what is going wrong here?

edit:
my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'MyApp',
        }),
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: 'MyApp'
    },
    resolve:{
        alias:{
            EVENTS: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/events"),
            MODELS: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/models"),
            GUI: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/gui"),
            HELPER: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/helper")
        }
    },
    devtool: 'eval-cheap-source-map',
    devServer: {
        watchContentBase: true,
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        port: 9000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use:['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

my buildscript is `webpack src/app.js -d --watch`

Comment: Could you please share your build script and webpack.config.js, so that we have a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: Sure, I've added the info thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the `-d` parameter from your build script. `-d` stands for devtool, but it is not followed by a parameter value in your command.

Comment: Seems to work for now. I'll look into it later how to setup this better. Thanks!